# How to fix some cvxpy matrix elements while allowing others to vary?

Tags: python, matrix, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I have an issue with cvxpy, and the documentation is so, so sparse! Was wondering if anyone could provide advice on how to make some elements of a matrix Variable fixed while letting others vary.

I have no issue providing my original code, but it's complicated, so here's a toy example.

```
import cvxpy as cvx 

A = cvx.Variable(12)

obj = cvx.Minimize(cvx.sum(A))

constraints = []
constraints += [A > -1]

A[1][1].value = 9 # ?? 

problem = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)
problem.solve()
```

??

Comment: Thoughts: unless I did something wrong, I noticed that I can't include an equality constraint. Can include two inequality constraints for each element that I want to fix?

Comment: **1:** Fix variables by constraints. Yes... this might seem weird, but is more or less the only safe way to do this in high-level modelling-frameworks and every *good* solver (-> complex pre-solve component) will show no slow-down (compared to low-level fixing). Example: `constraints += [A[1][1] == 9]` (this is a constraint -> `==`!) Of course, you can use most numpy/scipy indexing-tricks to make this nice for more complex examples **2:** Your example is strange as `A = cvx.Variable(12)` is a 1d-vector of 12 elements and `A[1][1].value = 9 # ??` looks like 2d-indexing / matrix-indexing.

Comment: **3:** I always considered accessing `my_var.value` only to be safe / allowed after solving and checking that there is a solution. A variable of some model not yet solved should not have any value! These things are only allowed for *parameters* (see docs; not really something helping with your problem) i suppose.

Comment: Hey Sascha, thank you so much for your time and your response! I really appreciate it! Sorry for the late feedback